# Cumulative sum in R not working with descending data

Tags: r, sum

I have the following data

```
customer_id      amount
1                 1000
2                   76
3                  111
4                 9099
5                 1111
```

I would like to get the accumulative sum of the amounts after sorting the amounts in descending order

I have tried

```
transform(result2, CumSumX=cumsum(result2[order(-result2$amount), "amount"]));
```

but it is not ordering my data

Comment: Just do `with(result2,  cumsum(amount[order(-amount)]))` or `with(result2, cumsum(sort(amount, decreasing = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can do it by using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(amount)) %>% mutate(CumSum = cumsum(amount))

 ID amount CumSum
1  4   9099   9099
2  5   1111  10210
3  1   1000  11210
4  3    111  11321
5  2     76  11397
```

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                 amount = c(1000,76,111,9099,1111))
```

Comment: I personally don't love dplyr usually (I was raised on base R), but that's pretty slick!

Comment: I used to think the same way before I learned and quite understood how to use it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you.

```
df_ordered <- result2[order(result2$amount,decreasing = TRUE),]
df_ordered$cumSum <- cumsum(df_ordered$amount)
df_ordered
```

Result:

```
  customer_id amount cumSum
          4   9099   9099
          5   1111  10210
          1   1000  11210
          3    111  11321
          2     76  11397
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
with(result2, cumsum(amount[order(-amount)]))
#[1]  9099 10210 11210 11321 11397
```